# Attach multiple services in amazon application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, dropwizard

I have two drop wizard services in running in AWS ECS instances and I need to use the single ALB for both of these services running in their own docker container and as part of the same ECS cluster.

In load balancer setting I can't see how can I map it to two services, please guide me as I need this to have less overhead and for coast saving purposes?

[image: configure LB image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a listener for each container port mapping, even if they're the same host.

You will need to add the additional listener(s) after the wizard.